# Refresh em uma <li>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Tenho um conteúdo dentro de um `<li>` que preciso fazer um refresh nela no evento `onclick`.
Só que dentro desta li existe uma função em `php`. Como isso seria possível?

Comment: o que faz uma funcition php dentro de um elemento html? isso não faz sentido, além do que, sem ver o código fica mais impossível ainda de entender...

Comment: Coloque seu código para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Manda o código ai?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.

Comment: Realmente como os colegas disseram, sem o código fica difícil de entender. Porém você tem que entender que JavaScript roda no navegador PHP não, e no seu caso PHP roda no servidor e JavaScript não. O PHP devolve HTML que por sua vez será interpretado pelo navegador. Não há ligação entre PHP e JavaScript. O que você está fazendo é imprimindo o resultado de uma função em PHP no HTML do `<li>`.